# Create new column that merges column names greater than 0

Tags: r, count, paste

I would like to work with combinations of `Beer` and `Wine` and `Spirits` and the `SUM` of the row total, for example:

```
df <- data.frame(
        Beer = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 3L),
        Wine = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L),
     Spirits = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L),
         SUM = c(2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 6L)
)
```

How can create a new column `COMBINE` that pastes together the `SUM` and column name with a value greater than 0. Something like this, however any `SUM` greater than 5 is considered as 5+.

```
Beer    Wine    Spirits    SUM     COMBINE
1        1        0        2       2Beer&Wine
1        1        1        3       3Beer&Wine&Spirits
1        0        0        1       1Beer
1        0        0        1       1Beer
3        0        0        3       3Beer
4        0        0        4       4Beer
0        1        1        2       2Wine&Spirits
0        1        1        2       2Wine&Spirits
3        2        1        6       5+Beer&Wine&Spirits
```

For some added context, the end desired result of all this is that I am looking to count the factors in `COMBINE`, although this is not the part that I am struggling with.

```
COMBINE    Count
1Beer        2
2Beer        0
3Beer        1
4Beer        1
5+Beer       0
1Wine        0
2Wine        0
.
.
.
2Wine&Spirits 2
.....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straightforward solution using `ifelse`:

```
d$COMBINE <- with(d, gsub("&$", "", 
                          paste0(ifelse(SUM > 5, "5+", SUM),
                                 ifelse(Beer > 0, "Beer&", ""),
                                 ifelse(Wine > 0, "Wine&", ""),
                                 ifelse(Spirits > 0, "Spirits", ""))))

  Beer Wine Spirits SUM             COMBINE
1    1    1       0   2          2Beer&Wine
2    1    1       1   3  3Beer&Wine&Spirits
3    1    0       0   1               1Beer
4    3    0       0   3               3Beer
5    4    0       0   4               4Beer
6    0    1       1   2       2Wine&Spirits
7    0    1       2   3       3Wine&Spirits
8    3    2       1   6 5+Beer&Wine&Spirits
```

To count factors you can use: `table(d$COMBINE)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with *aggregate*:

```
d$sum5 = pmin(5, d$Beer + d$Wine + d$Spirits)
d$count = 1
aggregate(count ~ (Beer>0) + (Wine>0) + (Spirits>0) + sum5, data=d, FUN=sum)

  Beer > 0  Wine > 0  Spirits > 0  sum5  count
1     TRUE     FALSE        FALSE     1      1
2     TRUE      TRUE        FALSE     2      1
3    FALSE      TRUE         TRUE     2      1
4     TRUE     FALSE        FALSE     3      1
5    FALSE      TRUE         TRUE     3      1
6     TRUE      TRUE         TRUE     3      1
7     TRUE     FALSE        FALSE     4      1
8     TRUE      TRUE         TRUE     5      1
```

Disregarding the sum (to give an example where not everything ends up being 1):

```
aggregate(count ~ (Beer>0) + (Wine>0) + (Spirits>0), data=d, FUN=sum)

  Beer > 0  Wine > 0  Spirits > 0  count
1     TRUE     FALSE        FALSE      3
2     TRUE      TRUE        FALSE      1
3    FALSE      TRUE         TRUE      2
4     TRUE      TRUE         TRUE      2
```